# 'function' object has no attribute '_default_manager' en django 2.1

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de listar los datos de mi tabla en mi template, pero me aparece este error:

> 'function' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

---

*Código del modelo:*

```
class persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    topipoid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    identificacion = models.IntegerField()
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fechacreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

---

*Código del View:*

```
class personalist(ListView):
    model = persona
    template_name = "persona/persona_listar.html"
```

*Código URL:*

```
urlpatterns = [
  path(r'', index, name='index'),
  path(r'nuevo/', persona, name='persona'),
  path(r'listar/', personalist.as_view()),
]
```

*Código Template:*

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}
{% block footer %}

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
         <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Tipo ID</td>
        <td>Direccion</td>
        <td>Fecha Creacion</td>

         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {% for persona in object_list %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ persona.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ persona.Nombre }}</td>
       <td>{{ persona.topipoid }} </td>
       <td>{{ persona.Direccion }}</td>


     </tr>
    {% endfor %}


    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Pon el error que te muestra

Answer (score 0):

Tiene bastante pinta de que estás llamando a una vista igual que a tu modelo, es decir, `persona`.

Aquí en tus URL tienes esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path(r'', index, name='index'),
  path(r'nuevo/', persona, name='persona'), ## <-- persona como view?
  path(r'listar/', personalist.as_view()),
]
```

que confirma el origen del posible error.
Cambia el nombre de la vista a `PersonaCreate` por ejemplo y modifica el código en consecuencia a ver si te resuelve tu problema.